# Permiso crear y eliminar tablas solo del mismo usuario que la crea en SQL server

Tags: sql

Existe algún permiso o se puede configurar de alguna manera el acceso de un usuario SQL SERVER para que pueda, entre otros permisos, crear tablas y eliminar esas tablas creadas por el mismo sin que pueda eliminar otras tablas creadas por otros usuarios? Tengo la versión SQL server 2016.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Probablemente tendrías que tener un esquema por usuario, pero eso suena a una pesadilla para el mantenimiento y administración.

Comment: Actualmente estoy conectando las aplicaciones a la base de datos con el usuario "sa" de sql sever, desde la aplicación se ejecutan procedimientos almacenados los cuales contienen instrucciones TransactSQL que crean y eliminan tablas durante su ejecución; el tema es que ahora quiero crear un usuario sólo para conectar aplicaciones, que tenga permisos de lectura y escritura de datos pero que también pueda crear y eliminar sus propias tablas y no pueda eliminar tablas de otro usuario.